# Read sql queries via pandas quickly with pyoracle

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using oracle sql developer and have built a script to read sql queries in parallel as well as under a thread. However, I have noticed no significant difference in speed by implementing this (even with chunksizes), than reading the table directly. Therefore, could my approach be wrong and what's the improvement to my approach, to speed things up?

For example:

```
#My table size is only 38k rows and this takes ~ 1.2 minutes to run
    def table(self, table = None, query = None, chunksize = None):
        from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
        with self._ENGINE.connect() as conn:
            tables = []
            if query is None and table is not None:
                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 8) as executor:
                    for results in executor.submit(pd.read_sql,f"SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ NAME FROM {table}", conn, chunksize=chunksize).result():
                        tables.append(results)
                table = pd.concat([pd.concat([x]) for x in tables])
                conn.close()
                return table
            else:
                print('something else')
```

Comment: Each Oracle DB connection can only do one db "operation" at a time.  So to speed up queries across threads, each thread would need its own connection.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Would you mind providing an example of this implementation?

Comment: Have a look at the old example https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/connection_pool.py  You can do something similar with each thread selecting a chunk of rows.  You'll probably find the latest version of cx_Oracle, now called python-oracledb faster, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)

Comment: @ChristopherJones Many thanks for the suggestion, luckily I am using python-oracledb back-end for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the following documentation:
[tuning fetch](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuningfetch)

It takes approximately `118 seconds` for the code above to run, whereas after a slight remodification:

```
    def table2(self, table = None, query = None):
        from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
        self._cursor.arraysize = 10000
        self._cursor.prefetchrows = 1000000
        tables = []
        start = time.time()
        if query is None and table is not None:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 8) as executor:
                for results in executor.submit(self._cursor.execute,f"SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ NAME FROM {table}").result():
                    tables.append(results)
        end = time.time()
        start_second = time.time()
        self._cursor.execute(f"SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ NAME FROM {table}").fetchall()
        end_second = time.time()
        print("Threadpool time: %s, fetchall time: %s" % (str(end-start), str(end_second-start_second)))
```

Takes the following time to execute:

```
Threadpool time: 1.0487918853759766, fetchall time: 0.48572492599487305
```

Comment: your question doesn't show what result you get and so we can also not compare it with the second.

Comment: @nbk well ... the answer I discovered works for my particular case so I'm sharing the difference between pandas, threading and fetchall. Although, if you want to test these results, you can use both function and set up a sqlalchemy engine using `oracledb` as your driver, and create a table with 38k rows in SQL, then try it all out.

Comment: Using PARALLEL hint in your case is very unlikely to give any performance improvement. The bottleneck is sending the data back to your python program which is serial. If your query is complex, such a hint may help.

Comment: For big fetches, you might want to keep prefetchrows at its default, otherwise you end up with double memory being allocated (one chunk for the arraysize buffer and one for the prefetch buffer) - but only save one round trip.

Comment: Thank you both for the advice. Although, @ChristopherJones, what's an example of a concurrent solution to the above? For example, with `fetchmany()`, how to run these concurrently so each thread retrieves a separate number of rows.

Comment: See the new 'answer' I added

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of fetching data from a single table using multiple connections.  Whether it's faster than a single thread doing a full table scan is something for you to check.  Maybe Python's GIL is a bottleneck.  Maybe your database is on a single disk instead of multiple disks, so there is no extra throughput possible.  Maybe the OFFSET/FETCH NEXT and ORDER BY are a limiting factor because the DB is busy doing work for other users (or maybe you're the only user so they are fast). Maybe for you it's what you do with the data when you get it in Python that will be a bottleneck.

Fundamentally from the Oracle side, tuning `arraysize` will be the biggest factor for any single SELECT that returns a large number of rows over a slower network.

```
# Fetch batches of rows from a table using multiple connections

import csv
import os
import platform
import threading

import oracledb

# To fetch everything, keep NUM_THREADS * BATCH_SIZE >= TABLE_SIZE

# number of rows to insert the demo table
TABLE_SIZE = 10000

# The degree of parallelism / number of connections to open
NUM_THREADS = 10

# How many rows to fetch in each thread
BATCH_SIZE = 1000

# Internal buffer size: Tune this for performance
ARRAY_SIZE = 1000

SQL = """
    select data
    from demo
    order by id
    offset :rowoffset rows fetch next :maxrows rows only
    """

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
pw = os.environ.get('PYTHON_PASSWORD')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')

if os.environ.get('DRIVER_TYPE') == 'thick':
    ld = None
    if platform.system() == 'Darwin' and platform.machine() == 'x86_64':
        ld = os.environ.get('HOME')+'/Downloads/instantclient_19_8'
    elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
        ld = r'C:\oracle\instantclient_19_17'
    oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=ld)

# Create a connection pool
pool = oracledb.create_pool(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs, min=NUM_THREADS, max=NUM_THREADS)

#
# Create the table for the demo
#
def create_schema():
    with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            connection.autocommit = True
            cursor.execute("""
                begin
                  begin
                    execute immediate 'drop table demo';
                    exception when others then
                      if sqlcode <> -942 then
                        raise;
                      end if;
                  end;

                  execute immediate 'create table demo (
                       id    number generated by default as identity,
                       data  varchar2(40))';

                  insert into demo (data)
                      select to_char(rownum)
                      from dual
                      connect by level <= :table_size;

                end;""", table_size=TABLE_SIZE)

# Write the data to separate CSV files
def do_write_csv(tn):
    with pool.acquire() as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.arraysize = ARRAY_SIZE
            f = open(f"emp{tn}.csv", "w")
            writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
            cursor.execute(SQL, rowoffset=(tn*BATCH_SIZE), maxrows=BATCH_SIZE)
            col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
            writer.writerow(col_names)
            while True:
                rows = cursor.fetchmany()  # extra call at end won't incur extra round-trip
                if not rows:
                    break
                writer.writerows(rows)
            f.close()


# Print the data to the terminal
def do_query(tn):
    with pool.acquire() as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.arraysize = ARRAY_SIZE
            cursor.execute(SQL, rowoffset=(tn*BATCH_SIZE), maxrows=BATCH_SIZE)
            while True:
                rows = cursor.fetchmany()  # extra call at end won't incur extra round-trip
                if not rows:
                    break
                print(f'Thread {tn}', rows)


#
# Start the desired number of threads.
#
def start_workload():
  thread = []
  for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
      t = threading.Thread(target=do_write_csv, args=(i,))
      #t = threading.Thread(target=do_query, args=(i,))
      t.start()
      thread.append(t)

  for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
      thread[i].join()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    create_schema()
    start_workload()
    print("All done!")
```