# how to improve the performance python script for extracting big size(3-4GB)of oracle table

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

I'm connecting to oracle database using python script and extracting around 10 tables. one table is having 3Gb of data it took around 4 hours to extract with below code and upload it to S3. How can we improve the performance of the below python script?

Different file format other than csv will improve the performance like parquet?

Any suggestions or solutions will be highly appreciated.

Below is the code I tried:

```
def extract_handler():
    # Parameters defined in cloudwatch event
    env = os.environ['Environment'] if 'Environment' in os.environ else 'sit'

    # FTP parameters
    host = f"/{env}/connet_HOSTNAME"
    username = f"/{env}/connect_USERNAME"
    password = f"/{env}/connect_PASSWORD"

    host = get_parameters(host)
    username = get_parameters(username)
    password = get_parameters(password)
    today = date.today()
    current_date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    con = None
    cur = None
    tables = ["table1", "table2","table3"........."table10"]
    bucket = "bucket_name"

    for table in tables:
        try:
            con = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, host, encoding="UTF-8")
            cur = con.cursor()
            logging.info('Successfully established the connection to Oracle db')
            table_name = table.split(".")[1]
            logging.info("######## Table name:"+ table +" ###### ")
            logging.info("****** PROCESSING:" +table_name+" *********")
            cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM  {}".format(table))
            count = cur.fetchone()[0]
            logging.info("Count:", count)
            if count > 0:
                cur1 = con.cursor()
                # Define the desired timestamp format
                timestamp_format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
                # Execute a query to read a table
                cur1.execute( "select * from {} where TRUNC(DWH_CREATED_ON)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1".format(table))
                batch_size = 10000
                rows = cur1.fetchmany(batch_size)
                csv_file = f"/tmp/{table_name}.csv"
                with open(csv_file, "w", newline="") as f:
                    # Add file_date column as the first column
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['file_date'] + [col[0] for col in cur1.description],
                                            delimiter='\t')
                    writer.writeheader()
                    logging.info("Header added to the table:" + table + "######")
                while rows:
                    for row in rows:
                        row_dict = {'file_date': current_date}
                        for i, col in enumerate(cur1.description):
                            if col[1] == cx_Oracle.DATETIME:
                                if row[i] is not None:
                                    row_dict[col[0]] = row[i].strftime(timestamp_format)
                                else:
                                    row_dict[col[0]] = ""
                            else:
                                row_dict[col[0]] = row[i]

                        with open(csv_file, "a", newline="") as f:
                            # Add file_date column as the first column
                            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['file_date'] + [col[0] for col in cur1.description],
                                                    delimiter='\t')
                            writer.writerow(row_dict)
                        # Fetch the next batch of 100 rows
                        rows = cur1.fetchmany(batch_size)
                logging.info("Records written to the temp file for the table :" + table + "######")
                s3_path = "NorthernRegion" + '/' + table_name + '/' + current_date + '/' + table_name + '.csv'
                s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='region-central-1')
                s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/' + table_name + '.csv', bucket, s3_path)
                logging.info(table + "File uploaded to S3 ######")
            else:
                logging.info('Table not having data')
                return 'Data is not refreshed yet, Hence quitting..'
            if cur1:
                cur1.close()

        except Exception as err:
            #Handle or log other exceptions such as bucket doesn't exist
            logging.error(err)
        finally:
            if cur:
                cur.close()
            if con:
                con.close()
        return "Successfully processed"
```

Comment: for every row you `with open(csv_file, "a", newline="")` this will be a pain point for sure

Comment: Does this really work at all?  For every `row in rows` you also `rows = cur1.fetchmany(batch_size)`

Comment: (1) Do as little string manipulation on the rows as possible.  Manipulate the results via the SQL instead. (2) parallelize the extract for very large tables. Divide the workload among forked background threads and use a MOD function on a PK-like value to distribute rows evenly among the threads. When all child processes are done, cat the result files together into one.

Comment: Check the manual [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance) and tune `arraysize` to reduce round-trips between the app and the database.  (Your batch_size is not used for internal buffer tuning by fetchmany). You might find the new Thin mode of the latest version of cx_Oracle (now called [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)) faster.  Don't do the `select count(*)` - instead just count the rows that you write.

Comment: If you try a multi-threaded approach, you will need to open different connections in each thread.

Comment: For a simple 'select from Oracle Database and write to CSV' example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75063284/4799035

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75419536/4799035