# Threading multiple fetchmany chunks independently

Tags: python, multithreading, python-oracledb

I have built a sqlalchemy+oracledb engine which fetches a sql query and returns this as a dataframe. However, I want to retrieve this table in chunks and have each chunk process concurrently, say at least 4 concurrent requests to each chunk. How can I achieve this? I have implement a `.map` method, but this is just as fast as not including it, probably not concurrent because its under a while loop?

For example:

```
class threadedEngine(Engine):
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print('oracle://%s:%s@' % (args))
        self._ENGINE =  create_engine('oracle://MY_DB', pool_pre_ping = True) 
        self._connection = self._ENGINE.raw_connection()
        self._cursor = self._connection.cursor()

    def self(self,chunk):
        dict_object = defaultdict(list)
        for inc, values in enumerate(chunk):
            dict_object[self._cursor.description[inc][0]].append(values)
        return dict_object

    def table(self, table = None, query = None, chunksize: bool = False):
        self._cursor.arraysize = 10000
        self._cursor.prefetchrows = 1000000
        if query is None and table is not None:
            start = time.time()
            if chunksize:
                table_dict = self._cursor.execute(f"SELECT /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL(AUTO) */ * FROM {table}")
                i = 0
                while True:
                    chunk = table_dict.fetchmany(self._cursor.arraysize)
                    if not chunk: 
                        break
                    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
                        dict_object = list(executor.map(self.self, chunk))
                result = pd.DataFrame(dict_object)
            end = time.time()
            print("Total Time: %s" % (end-start))
            return result
```

Comment: You must not name a method as `self`!

Comment: Since each Oracle DB connection can only do one 'operation' (e.g SELECT) at a time, you will need to have new connections in each thread.  You may want to do this in the native driver, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75351686/read-sql-queries-via-pandas-quickly-with-pyoracle